# Filter and get values using OR and AND conditions programmatically in Django

Tags: django

I am querying a set of objects with a condition like this:

```
filters_for_dates_report = ['birthday', 'job_anniversary', 'wedding_anniversary']

values_list_for_dates_report = ['id', 'name', 'date']

for filter_for_dates_report in filters_for_dates_report:
        filter_dict.update({filter_for_dates_report: {
                        filter_for_dates_report + "__range" : [start_date, end_date]
                        }})

list_of_Q = [Q(**{key: val}) for key, val in filter_dict.items()]


if list_of_Q:
    model_details = Model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, list_of_Q))
                                 .values(*values_list_for_dates_report)
```

Now I want to `exclude` the objects which have `null` values for `filter_for_dates_report` attributes.
A direct query would be

```
Model.objects.filter(
                     Q(birthday__range=[start_date, end_date] & birthday__isnull=False))
             .values(*values_list_for_dates_report)
```

But how can I do this for multiple values wherein I want only the values within that range and also which are not null for multiple `filter_for_dates_report` attributes.
Something like:

```
Model.objects.filter(
                     (Q(birthday__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(birthday__isnull=False)) | 
                     (Q(marriage_anniversary__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(marriage_anniversary__isnull=False)) | 
                     (Q(job_anniversary__range=[start_date, end_date]) & Q(job_anniversary__isnull=False)))
             .values(*values_list_for_dates_report)
```

Comment: Are you filtering the ***same field*** named `filter_for_dates_report` again and again? I didn't get your logic here

Comment: No. They are different fields. Since the `for` loop variable will be the same. I wrote it like that. I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 1):

loop over and reduce it with OR operator :

```py
import operator
filter_dict = []
queryset = Model.objects.all()
for filter_for_dates_report in filters_for_dates_report:
    filter_dict.append(Q(**{
        filter_for_dates_report + "__range": [start_date, end_date]
    }))

queryset = Model.objects.filter(
    reduce(operator.or_, filter_dict)
).values(*values_list_for_dates_report)
```

This will create a `queryset` with filters **OR** with what you put in the loop.

You dont need to add a `__isnull` if you add a `__range`

Comment: Doesnt this also query objects whose `filter_for_dates_report` attributes will be `null`? My code in the question is also similar. I want to query the objects whose attributes are in the `range` and also `notnull`

Comment: if its in `range` its `notnull` by design, do you want in `range` OR `notnull` ?

Comment: Yes. But I am also getting the values of objects which are null. Maybe it is because of `.values(*values_list_for_dates_report)`?

Comment: That another problem, because you ask for `'id', 'name', 'date'`, they can be null but they have for sure a `filter_for_dates_report` field date `not null` maybe you want to exclude if `'id', 'name', 'date'` are `null`

Comment: Oh ok. I guess I am getting the error because of that. Sorry. I asked the wrong question.